# TargetInvocationException when lambda returns object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using C# and Entity Framework with SQL Server 2014 to create a simple own project.

I have a model class named "UserDomain" (is a table in the Entity).

I can make LINQ perfectly returning an IQueryable:

```
(from user in Context.Users select user);
```

But when I invoke a method that returns UserDomain the exception occurs, for example:

```
(from user in Context.Users select user).ToList();
```

or

```
FirstOrDefault();
```

What is strange is `Count()` returns 1, which indicates not to be null and there is a user in the base called jfrode. If I use `users.Any (x => x.Login ==" jfrode ")` in code it returns true.

**StackTrace**: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4daf1ac3ce6536b262a69785577c6dfe

**GitHub Project**: https://github.com/JFRode/FrenteDeCaixa

Thanks!

Comment: maybe returning Count =1, but it still can be a null value. Check with a breakpoint!

Comment: There is a user in the base called jfrode. If I use `users.Any (x => x.Login ==" jfrode ")` in code it returns true.

Comment: what is the different between users (which includes jfrode)  and Context.Users?

Comment: Can you show us the full stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question, there is now StackTrace =)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The error occurs because in my domains/models I dont have a constructor with no parameters.

I was using a multiparameter constructor because I use it in Builder.
But I need to declare an empty constructor as well.

Thank you all!